# (Firebase) After login with facebook, it won't return to my app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

When I log in with Facebook in on a Real Device It will be stuck on the Facebook login page and don' return back to my app.

I have put facebook code in URL Schemes and put all code that need to put in info.plist.

This is all the code that i use to login Facebook by using firebase.

In Viewdidload

```
facebookButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomFBLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Code that i use in Viewcontroller.

```
@objc func handleCustomFBLogin(sender:UIButton!){
        LoginManager().logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (result, error) in

            guard let result = result else {
                print("No result found")
                return
            }
            if result.isCancelled {
                print("Facebook Login Cancelled")
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Process error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Logged in")
                self.showEmailAddress()
                self.actionfb()
            }
        }
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?){
        if(error != nil){
            print(error!)
            return
        }else{
            print("Successfully Logged in using facebook")
            showEmailAddress()
        }

    }

    func actionfb(){
        let accessToken = AccessToken.current
        guard (accessToken?.tokenString) != nil else {return}
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken!.tokenString)
        // Perform login by calling Firebase APIs
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in

            if let error = error {
                self.showAlert(title: "error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoGo", sender: nil)
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        }

    }

    func showEmailAddress(){

        GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, birthday, picture"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
            if(err != nil){
                print("Failed to start GraphRequest", err ?? "")
                return
            }
            print(result ?? "")

        }

    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton){
        print("Logged out of Facebook")
    }
```

In Appdelegate

```
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

This will happen only when i had test on real device!!, but in simulation this can work normally

Comment: Did you solve this, I have the same issue and the below answer doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is the solution, but this fixed it for me.
I copied the  OAuth redirect URI from my firebase, under Authentication -> Facebook
[image]

And then on my Facebook developer page, under Products -> Facebook Login -> Settings, I pasted it into Valid OAuth Redirect URIs
[image]

I then logged in by entering in my username and password into of clicking "Login with Facebook" and the error stopped happening.

I have no idea if the error will return, maybe this will be helpful to someone though.